# Adding text input that shows average of several jQuery UI sliders

Tags: jquery-ui, average, uislider

I have several jQueryUI sliders working with this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($)
{
    $( '.rwmb-slider' ).each( function() {

        var $this = $( this ),
            $input = $this.siblings( 'input' ),
            $valueLabel = $this.siblings( '.rwmb-slider-value-label' ).find( 'span' ),
            value = $input.val(),
            options = $this.data( 'options' );

        if ( !value )
        {
            value = 0;
            $input.val( 0 );
            $valueLabel.text( '0' );
        }
        else
        {
            $valueLabel.text( value );
        }

        // Assign field value and callback function when slide
        options.value = value;
        options.slide = function( event, ui )
        {
            $input.val( ui.value );
            $valueLabel.text( ui.value );

        };

        $this.slider( options );    

    });

});
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/q2BwE/

Everything works good but I'm struggling integrating in this code a function that allows me to display in a text input an average of the sliders which value is different than '0'.

Can you help me guys? Thank you

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well? A jsFiddle would help too.

Comment: Thanks, I've just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q2BwE/2/)**.

I added a text field (`<input name="average" type="text" readonly />`) to display the average that gets calculated after any of the sliders finish moving. Then I added the following code to do the calculation:

```
options.change = function (event, ui) {
    var avg = 0;
    var div = 0;
    $('.rwmb-slider').each(function () {
        avg += ($(this).slider('value'));
        if($(this).slider('value')>0)div++
    })
    $('input[name=average]').val(avg/div);
};
```

Comment: Great..pretty close thank you! What I miss now is to calculate the avarage only of the sliders with a value different than '0'. I mean that "/3" should'nt be hardcoded. Example slider1: **100** / slider2: **50** / slider3: **0**, the average should be 150/2 = 75. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Thank you very much j08691! You are my saviour. Works perfect.